# How to make tidy ignore TT code in html.tt templates?

Tags: php, perl, xhtml, tidy, template-toolkit

I have some TT templates that I want tidy-up a little. I use tidy on the command-line.

my command looks like:

```
$ tidy -utf8  --preserve-entities y -indent -wrap 120 file.html.tt
```

Unfortunately if I have code like:

```
[% aoh.unshift({ label => '', value => 'All types' }); %]
```

It ends up in the resulting file as:

```
[% aoh.unshift({ label =&gt; '', value =&gt; 'All types' }); %]
```

The same happens with Template Toolkit code in tag attributes, eg:

```
<a href="[%%20%20c.url_for('/content/edit').query('data_type'%20=%3Edata_type%20)%20%]" >
```

What would be the needed options to make tidy ignore everything between "[%" and "%]"? 
Same question holds true for PHP start and end tags.

Thanks.

Comment: Hm, tidy isn't really meant to tidy up templates, but actual HTML. You can however set `fix-uri` to false to avoid your href's being processed, and there's a _small_ chance `assume-xml-procins` can do something with php tags, but I doubt it.

Comment: Ok, but all I want is make tidy ignore some content as it would ignore HTML comments. I will try however.

Comment: To put it another way:
What is the proper tool for the job(if not tidy)?

Comment: That's another question, to which I unfortunately have to say: I know of none. Tidy has been stagnant for years now, maybe you can extend HTML Purifier somewhat, but it'd take some work. The easiest solution I can come up with is to remove all instructions from the file, substituting them with 'safe' placeholders, and after tidy's work edit them in again.

Comment: Surrounding Template/PHP/ASP/etc code with HTML comments and then removing comments worked for some of the code but not for tag attributes where tidy escaped them :). Pain in the ass. Thanks however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow extending the ideas here, why not replace TT snippets for something completely harmless and after tidy put original things back. In code below, I am replacing for comments like `<!-- sn20 -->`:

```
use File::Slurp;
my $template = read_file(shift);

# replace TT snippets with <!-- snNN -->
my %snip = ();
my $id   = 0;
$template =~ s/ \[% (.*?) %\] / $snip{++$id} = $1; "<!-- sn$id -->" /gxse;

# run tidy
open my $tidy_fh, '|-', 'tidy -utf8  --preserve-entities y -indent -wrap 120 >tidy_out'
    or die;
print $tidy_fh $template;
close $tidy_fh;

# fix code back
my $template_tidied = read_file('tidy_out');
$template_tidied =~ s/<!-- sn(\d+) -->/ "[%$snip{$1}%]" /ge;

# print the result
print $template_tidied;
```

Comment: That's a good idea. I will try a combination of your code and the first approach. Thanks... it is getting harder to shoose the right answer :). This is called collaboration!

Comment: @Berov - I thought of tidying templates long time ago, but never proceed to actual experiments. You really pushed me forward by your question, thanks for that.

Comment: And I will implement tidying for templates in 
https://github.com/kberov/MYDLjE using your idea, @bvr. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

What if you temporarily disguise your TT tags?

```
$ perl -pie 's/\[%/<!--\[ %/g; s/%\]/% \]-->/g' file.html.tt
$ tidy -utf8  --preserve-entities y -indent -wrap 120 file.html.tt
$ perl -pie 's/<!--\[ %/\[%/g; s/% \]-->/%\]/g' file.html.tt
```

The first command will convert all your TT elements into HTML comments, the last command changes them back.

Comment: ok, but what about TT in tag attributes?
As I commented above I tried it. The result is:
<a href=
        "%3C!--%20[%%20%20c.url_for('/content/edit').query('data_type'%20=%3Edata_type%20)%20%]%20--%3E"
may be I will have to try to use something different in tag attributes.